HDFS datanode: Couldn't resolve the hostname to an IP address
I'm configuring the Virtual Machine with Hadoop ecosystem using Docker, VirtualBox, with Ubuntu 24.04. For now, I'm using a docker-compose.yaml to run multiple services, including namenode, datanode, resourcemanager, and nodemanager. Others such as cassandra and kafka. I forward the ports with VirtualBox's settings successfully.
The official image I'm using is here. However, I can pull only the version 3.3.6 (The lastest one is 3.4.0 currently). Then, I create a folder with docker-compose.yaml, hadoop.env, and a Dockerfile files.
Here is the docker-compose.yaml. I attempt to add the hostname for the datanode according to another post, which tries resolves the getaddrinfo failed issue.
services:
  namenode:
      build: .
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: namenode
      command: ["hdfs", "namenode"]
      ports:
        - 9870:9870
      env_file:
        - ./hadoop.env
      environment:
          ENSURE_NAMENODE_DIR: "/tmp/hadoop-root/dfs/name"
      networks:
        - hadoop_network
  datanode:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: datanode
      command: ["hdfs", "datanode"]
      env_file:
        - ./hadoop.env
      depends_on:
      - namenode
      networks:
        - hadoop_network
  resourcemanager:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      hostname: resourcemanager
      command: ["yarn", "resourcemanager"]
      ports:
         - 8088:8088
      env_file:
        - ./hadoop.env
      volumes:
        - ./test.sh:/opt/test.sh
  nodemanager:
      image: apache/hadoop:3.3.6
      command: ["yarn", "nodemanager"]
      env_file:
        - ./hadoop.env
networks:
  hadoop_network:
    driver: bridge

Here is my hadoop.env. The only add on is the HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.webhdfs.enabled=true, which allows me to use the web HDFS RESTful API.
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.default.name=hdfs://namenode
CORE-SITE.XML_fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.namenode.rpc-address=namenode:8020
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.replication=1
HDFS-SITE.XML_dfs.webhdfs.enabled=true
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
MAPRED-SITE.XML_yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.map.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
MAPRED-SITE.XML_mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=resourcemanager
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.pmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec=600
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled=false
YARN-SITE.XML_yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications=10000
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent=0.1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues=default
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor=1
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity=100
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state=RUNNING
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue=*
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay=40
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings=
CAPACITY-SCHEDULER.XML_yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable=false

The Dockerfile, where I build the entire Hadoop version 3.3.6 with environment variables for the hadoop.env, following the post:
FROM apache/hadoop:3.3.6

ENV HADOOP_HOME=/home/username/hadoop
ENV PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin

ENV JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
ENV HADOOP_INSTALL=$HADOOP_HOME
ENV HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
ENV HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
ENV HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
ENV HADOOP_YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_HOME
ENV HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native
ENV HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

# Add any additional configurations or installations here

The verification steps are:

After running the command sudo docker compose up, following the documentation, I can PUT to the namenode with http://localhost:9870/webhdfs/v1/path/example.txt?op=CREATE&overwrite=true. I failed with the command docker-compose up -d.
The response header has the status code 307 with the location to be used for writing data. I PUT again with the location and get the error message: http://datanode:9864/webhdfs/v1/path/example.txt?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=true
The error message Couldn't resolve the hostname to an IP address, Verify Url: http://datanode:9864/webhdfs/v1/path/example.txt?op=CREATE&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:9000&createflag=&createparent=true&overwrite=true
The error message in the console in terms of NestJS implementation:

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND datanode
    at Function.AxiosError.from (D:\software development\kafka-nest\node_modules\.pnpm\axios@1.7.2\node_modules\axios\lib\core\AxiosError.js:89:14)
    at RedirectableRequest.handleRequestError (D:\software development\kafka-nest\node_modules\.pnpm\axios@1.7.2\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:610:25)
    at RedirectableRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at ClientRequest.eventHandlers.<computed> (D:\software development\kafka-nest\node_modules\.pnpm\follow-redirects@1.15.6\node_modules\follow-redirects\index.js:38:24)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:500:9)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:169:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:128:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
    at Axios.request (D:\software development\kafka-nest\node_modules\.pnpm\axios@1.7.2\node_modules\axios\lib\core\Axios.js:45:41)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

How can I ensure the datanode's address? Any help is highly appreciated.

The returned hostname address is what the namenode sees, which is correct. You'll need to replace it prior to the PUT request with localhost and port forward port 9864
Modifying any datanode settings to report a different address would break the namenode connection to it

Appreciate the reply. I removed the hostname, which lead to docker container id: http://d937a3d58503:9864/webhdfs/v1. Could you elaborate a little bit more regarding replace it prior to the PUT request with localhost and port forward port 9864? Thanks.

You're calling a PUT to the namenode. That returns a response with a different address. I was suggesting doing a string replacement. Otherwise, you could run the nest service from the same docker compose file so that it can resolve all container ids / hostnames within the Docker network

The Ubuntu environment in VirtualBox is intended for isolation. I've made several changes. Firstly. forward the ports 9846:9846 under the datanode. Secondly, after PUT the namenode, the 307 redirect header location has been changed to localhost, i.e., http://localhost:9864/webhdfs/v1. The error message changed to 403 forbidden, which I believe is another issue. I'll vote to close this one. Again, thank you for your time and help.
